# Linking when using I18n Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new with Ruby on Rails and I spent the night trying to get my translation with I18n to work. I got 2 locale, swedish(sv) and english(en). I finally got the url working with the /en and /sv working like this: domain/en/services. But the problem appears in my nav menu where I'm trying to have a link_to and at the same time have the t to be able to translate the nav menu item.

```
<li><%= link_to "t :NavTjänster", tjanster_path %></a></li>.
```

This is the only way to make the link work correctly with the /en/ or /sv/. t:NavTjänster is used for the translation but the link should say Tjänster in swedish or Services in english, now it appears as t:NavTjänster in the nav menu. How can I do both the link_to and the t:NavTjänster at the same time?

Thanks a lot in advance! I would appreciate if there is someone could guide me on this one!

Comment: Try `<%= link_to t("NavTjänster"), tjanster_path %>`

Comment: How does `</a>` come from?

Comment: Sorry, the </a> shouldn't be there. Removed it and it still didn't work. Thanks for noticing though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `"t :NavTjänster"` will literally display that string exactly as you typed it. You will need to rewrite the string as ruby code eg try:

```
<li><%= link_to t(:NavTjänster), tjanster_path %></li>.
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! This worked great! I accedently put a </a> there, ofcourse that shouldn't be there!

Comment: hehe thanks I didn't spot that. I've removed it from my example :)

Comment: I'm happy this worked even though it messed up by nav menu icon. Do you happen to also know what I can do about this: '<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight:bold;color:#5ec52f;margin-right:6px;font-size:14px;"></span><%= link_to t(:NavTjänster), tjanster_path %></li>' It moved the glyphicon and menu item out of place :/

Comment: That sounds like a brand new question ;) (also code formatting is awful in comments)

Comment: Thanks a million times for your help anyway! :)